# Ruby script in ERB not being read

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

**This is the index.html.erb:**

```
<h1>Bookmarks</h1>
t
<% @books.each do |b| %>
  <div class="book">
    e
    <div class="row">
      s
      <div class="col-md-1">
        t
        <p class="rank-this-week">
          <%= b.rank_this_week %> </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <p class="title"> <%= b.title %> </p>
        <p class="author">by  <%= b.author %></p>
        <p class="publisher">(<%= b.publisher %>)</p>
        <p class="description"> <%= b.description %> </p>
        <%= link_to 'See all Editorial Reviews', b %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <p class="weeks-on-list"><%= b.weeks_on_list %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**This is the books controller**

```
 class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books = Book.all
  end

  def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @reviews = @book.reviews
  end
end
```

I've routed the resources in **routes.rb** via `resources :books` and all of the object's elements exist in the `db/migrate`. And books has been seeded with tons of entries. Also ran `rake db:seed`.The problem is that when viewing the page, only The `<h1>` tag bookmarks, and the `t` are displayed. Nothing else.

Please help, really trying to crack down on RoR. Any help appreciated.

EDIT: The seeds file is pretty big but here is a sample of what it follows consistently.

```
b1 = Book.create(title: "American Sniper", author: "Chris Kyle, Scott        McEwen, Jim DeFelice", description: "A memoir about battlefield experiences in Iraq by the Navy SEALs sniper.", publisher: "Morrow/HarperCollins", weeks_on_list: 63, rank_this_week: 1)
b2 = Book.create(title: "Unbroken", author: "Laura Hillenbrand", description: "An Olympic runnerâ€™s story of survival as a prisoner of the Japanese in World War II after his plane went down over the Pacific.", publisher: "Random House", weeks_on_list: 25, rank_this_week: 2)
b3 = Book.create(title: "Wild", author: "Cheryl Strayed", description: "A womanâ€™s account of the life-changing 1,100-mile solo hike she took along the Pacific Crest Trail in 1995.", publisher: "Vintage", weeks_on_list: 95, rank_this_week: 3)
```

Comment: Looks like `@books` is empty

Comment: This is because you don't have any records in `books` table, so `@books` is empty. So it has no records to loop here `<% @books.each do |b| %>`. Create a record and check.

Comment: I should, add I also seeded books, and raked db.

Comment: @user3239012 : can you post your seed file's code? How you make store data? Please verify that Books table has records. run `rails c` then do `Book.all.count` which will return you the total number of records

Comment: Please show us your controller where you create @books relation.

Comment: Added the seeds file

Comment: And I rain book.all.count and it returned with "0" as books entries. But I've ran the rake several times.

Comment: @user3239012 - Please change all `create` to `create!` - it will raise an exception if there are any unsatisfied validations. Then rerun seed and fix validation errors.

Comment: "ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: rank_this_week"

But rank_this_week is clearly in the books active record as "t.integer :rank_this_week"

Comment: @user3239012 : You might be miss spell somewhere `rank_this_week` instead of `rank_this_week:`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it thanks to a ton of the comments! I realized when I was running rake db:seed nothing was going through but it was most likely a typo causing a seeding error.